# IOS Build failed: unknown oid 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches' (React-Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

Trying to publish my first React Native Expo app on Apple App Store (it is already in Google Play store), I go  `eas build --platform ios` in the terminal. From there it asks me to log in with my AppleId which I do. Then it says build failed.

In the 'Pre-install hook' build details log on Expo.dev, I get this error message:

1. Script 'eas-build-pre-install' is present in package.json, running
   it...
2. yarn run v1.22.17
3. $ sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
4. [stderr] sysctl: unknown oid 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches'
5. [stderr] error Command failed with exit code 1.
6. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation
   about this command.
7. yarn exited with non-zero code: 1

Is this because Im on a Windows PC, and it can only be done on a Mac or some bs?

Files are here: https://github.com/RasmusKvejborg/SecondsTillDeadApp

Answer (score 0):

Remove:
"eas-build-pre-install": "sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288"
from package.json works for me